# AngularJS - How to bind multiple dynamically added elements to other elements in different sections of HTML?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I apologize if I worded the question incorrectly, I am attempting to build a survey builder and I am running into a problem. Here is the link to an example plunker:

Updated:
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fb4EVGVp6h90sWfFRfQj?p=preview)

JS:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('FormBuilder');

    var stageController = function($scope, componentBuilder) {

            //var test = "<div>test<button>Im a Button</button></div>";
            $scope.components = [];
            $scope.components2 = [];

            $scope.selectedComponentIndex = -1;

            //$scope.list = [{html:test}];
            //$scope.componentSettings = "";
            $scope.showComponentSettings = function(componentName, index) {
                $scope.componentSettings = componentName;
                $('#navTab a[href="#componentSettingsPage"]').tab('show');
            };
            $scope.addMultipleChoice = function() {

                var component = componentBuilder.createMultipleChoice();
                $scope.components2.push(component);
                $scope.components.push(component.name);
            };

            $scope.addTextEntry = function() {

                var component = componentBuilder.createTextEntry();
                $scope.components.push(component);
            };

            $scope.addReadOnlyTextEntry = function() {

                var component = componentBuilder.createReadOnlyTextEntry();
                $scope.components.push(component);
            };

            $scope.delete = function(index) {

                $scope.components.splice(index, 1);
            };
        };

    app.controller("stageController", stageController);

}());
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
<div ng-controller="stageController">
  <!-- div>
    <div ui-sortable="" ng-model="list">
      <div ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">
        {{item}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div-->
  <div>
  Value of scope.inner = {{components}}
</div>
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div ng-include="" src="'nav.html'" style="width: 300px; display: table-cell;"></div>
    <div ng-include="" src="'stage.html'" style="display: table-cell;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="multipleChoice">
<div class="multipleChoice"></div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="textEntry">
 <div class="textEntry"></div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="readOnlyTextEntry">
 <div class="readOnlyTextEntry"></div>
</script>
```

UPDATED question and example: 
Please see my current plunker for the problem I am having. The plunker shows an example form builder that allows a user to added various components to build a form, this example allows multiple choice, text entry, and read only text entry components.

The left nav contains two tabs, one for the components and another for custom settings such as changing the question label or adding more choices to a component. My current problem is that I don't know the best method/practice to bind elements on the item settings to a specific form component in the collection.

So if a user adds a multiple choice component, clicks on it, it will show the item settings, and then be able to modifying the component settings for that specific component.
I hope this is more clear, any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do. "I am running into the problem on how to set up the settings html area binded to multiple components?"

Comment: Yes, you should use a template. Based on the type required, you'd load a different template.

Comment: When the template is loaded how is that data binded to the specific form component?

Comment: @OuwenHuang, I updated the plunker and question, I hope this clarifies my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @CaspNZ, I updated question and plunker for clarification.

Comment: What you need to do now is isolate the problem to one small thing - like binding one element to your HTML. At the moment, your plnkr is extremely large which means it's unlikely anyone will be able to get to the bottom of the problem - there are too many possible causes.